# Global function in ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I want to use a global function in different controllers, components, etc.

```
function myFunction(param){
    ...
    return result;
}
```

Is a global js function the best way to do it in Ember?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perfect use for a service:

```
App.MyFunctionService = Ember.Service.extend({
    function myFunction(param){
        ...
        return result;
    }
});
```

You can inject it anywhere you need it by doing:

```
myFunction: Ember.service.inject()
```

or

```
somethingElse: Ember.service.inject('myFunction')
```

You can setup an [initializer](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#toc_initializers) to inject it automatically into controllers, components and anywhere else you may need it.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your logic into some file inside `app` directory:

```
# app/utils/my-function.js
export default function myFunction() {
  return 2 + 40;
}
```

And use it wherever you want:

```
# app/posts/index/route.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import myFunction from 'my-project/utils/my-function';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {

    return myFunction();

  }
}
```